# VBA: how to verify a bound textbox in a subform

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I'm using ms-access, and I have a form that lists ingredients in the subform, along with the percentage of the ingredient in the product (as decimals eg. .4, .6 with 1 being 100%). I have a bound textbox that shows the total sum of the "Percentage" column (=Sum[Percentage]) the name of this textbox is Sum1.
What I want is for the main form to not allow you to continue until the bound textbox equals to 1. I found the subform event onExit (accessed in the main form) to be sufficient. As in, when you're in the main form and click in the subform, you shouldn't be able to click outside the subform until that textbox equals the sum of 1.
I can't figure out the vba code for it though. If I put the code like this:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub I_O_Subform_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
If Sum1 <> 1 Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Total Percentage must equal to 1"
End If
End Sub
```

-then once I go into the subform, I can't exit at all, even if the textbox does equal to 1.
I've tried doing it like this:

```
Private Sub I_O_Subform_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
If Forms!Outputs.I_O_Subform.Sum1 <> 1 Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Total Percentage must equal to 1"
End If
End Sub
```

but I just get Error "438": Object doesn't support this body or method.
and if I do

```
Private Sub I_O_Subform_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
If I_O_Subform.Sum1 <> 1 Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Total Percentage must equal to 1"
End If
End Sub
```

then it also doesn't understand.
can anyone help?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this reference:

```
If Me!I_O_Subform.Form!Sum1.Value <> 1 Then
```

where `I_O_Subform` must be the name of the subform *control* (which may differ from the name of the subform).

Comment: it now goes through whether it's at 1 or not. new code: `Private Sub I_O_Subform_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
If Me!I_OSub.Form!Sum1.Value <> 1 Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Total must equal 1"
End If
End Sub` I_OSub is the name of the control

Comment: Put in a line to check the value: `Debug.Print Me!I_OSub.Form!Sum1.Value`.